# How do I fit a photo inside the IEEE biography photo frame "ieeetrans class format"?

Tags: ieeetran, biography

How do I fit a photo inside the IEEE biography photo frame  "ieeetrans class format".
I have tried this command:

```
\begin{biography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{apple.png}}]{\textbf{Lorem ipsum}}
```

and the output is:

[image]

and this command:

```
\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{apple.png}}]{\textbf{Lorem ipsum}}
```

and the output is:

[image]

the best I reached is by moving the photo manually. I managed to move it vertically using `\raisebox{-3.1cm\height}`

however, couldn't find any code to move it horizontally without affecting the text

I think the ieeetrans.cls used is an old version, probably the 1996 one (version 2.5.4); hence, non of the above commands have worked.

Comment: ieeetrans is even older than IEEEtrans, which is being replaced by the new IEEE template (https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/tools-for-ieee-authors/ieee-article-templates/).  I keep waiting for CTAN and MikTeX to get the new version, but so far no joy.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{example-image}}]{\textbf{\LipsumPar{1}}}
\end{IEEEbiography}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried this command before (Example 2) and didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Copy the solution and run it.  If it works, figure out what is different between it and your version.